# Observable returns array of objects, but cannot access object properties

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm just learning Angular and been battling this all weekend. I have a http call to pull a collection of Schedule objects. The objects render in the DOM, but I cannot access the properties in my component class which I need to do to manipulate the output.

My service

```
public getSchedule(model: GetSchedule): Observable<Schedule[]> {
        console.log('called get schedule in the service');
        console.log(model);
        console.log(environment.urls.appointment.getSchedule);
        return this.http.post<Schedule[]>(environment.urls.appointment.getSchedule , model);
```

My component

```
public schedules: Schedule[];
daySelected:string;

 public getSchedule(){
      console.log(this.daySelected);
      let time = new Date(this.daySelected)
      let date = this.datePipe.transform(time, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
      const search = new GetSchedule();
      search.date = date;
      //search.plant = this.shipment.origin.id;
      search.plant = "1300";
      search.transitType =1;
      search.isPreloaded=this.isPreloaded;

      this.appointmentService.getSchedule(search).subscribe((schedules)=>{
        this.schedules=schedules;
        console.log(this.schedules); <---------This prints out the array of all schedules properly
        console.log(this.schedules.startTime); <--------------------This returns undefined
      });
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class = "col-sm-4">
            <ng-container *ngIf="schedules?.StartTime">
            <div *ngFor="let schedule of schedules; trackBy:trackDay; let i = index;" >
                <div><input type="radio" class="hidden" name="slot" [(ngModel)]="slotSelected" (change)="scheduleSlot(slotSelected)" id="{{schedules.indexOf(schedule)}}" value={{i}}>
                <label [ngClass]="{'disabled': schedule.Block ==1}" class="radio" for="{{schedules.indexOf(schedule)}}">{{schedule.StartTime}}</label></div>
            </div>
            </ng-container>
        </div>
```

If I remove the elvis operator in the ngIf the page displays with the correct start time, but if I try to console.log the start time it returns undefined. Keeping the elvis operator results in nothing displaying.

The api call returns an array containing 72 objects with the following form in the browser console:
(72)[{...}, {...},{...}....]. Expanding that reveals
0:{*list of all properties with correct values*}

The schedule has a property for slot which is a number 1-12 to represent a two hour window. Its returning 6 entries per slot so I need to be able to use find(x=>x.startTime == "8:00") to only return one entry per slot. But whenever I add that startTime is thrown as undefined.

Any ideas?

Comment: Array does not have a StartTime property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem, and it wasn't with my code but with what was getting sent back in the API call. It was a naming issue. What was getting sent back was StartTime, I was looking for startTime because everything else in this project follows camel case. A definite facepalm moment.
Now I just have to figure out where to put the Find code to filter out duplicates

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you don't define which element within the array you want to draw from. Remember, `startTime` is a property on each object WITHIN the array, not on the array itself. Thus this won't work:

```
console.log(this.schedules.startTime);
```

Whereas this will work:

```
console.log(this.schedules[0].startTime);
```

Comment: Isn't that what the this operator does? Regardless after making that change I'm still seeing the problem. The part that is confusing me is that removing this``` schedules?.StartTime``` to just this ```schedules``` results in the data (schedule.startTime) displaying properly.

Comment: This is definitely your issue. And no, nothing about the operator you're using will resolve this, because the property literally doesn't exist on the data structure you're asking for it from.

Comment: If I use this.schedules[1] the console correctly pulls out the member at element 1 and outputs all properties. But if I add on the .startTime it still reads undefined

Comment: Do you know for certain that the `startTime` property exists on every object in your array?

Comment: It does indeed. I'll add a screenshot of the output from the console